# Creating additional space in tabular for \dfrac, while vertically centering multirow and other cells

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, amsmath, vertical-spacing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\large

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | M{1.5cm} | M{9.5cm} | M{1cm} | M{4.5cm} |}
    \hline
    \centering \multirow{6}{*}{1} &
    $f(3) = 100$
    \par \medskip
    $a=\dfrac{50}{21}-\dfrac{13}{42}b$ & \hfill \textbf{A} & B
    \tabularnewline
    \cline{2-4}
    & $3x^2-x-4=(3x-4)(x+1)$ & \hfill \textbf{C} & D
    \tabularnewline
    \cline{2-4}
    & \vspace{0.15cm} $f(-1) = 0$ or $f(\dfrac{4}{3}) = 0$
    \par \medskip
    $b=-\dfrac{2}{3}a$ & \hfill \textbf{E} & F
    \tabularnewline
    \cline{2-4}
    & $a=3, \; b=-2$ & \hfill \textbf{G} & H
    \tabularnewline
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This code gives the following output:
[image]

The bottom \dfrac at rows AB and EF are getting cut off by the \cline. **Is there a way to create additional space for the fractions while maintaining vertical centering of the other cells in the row? (The cells with the \dfrac should also be vertically centered)**

The vertical centering of the multirow column (labelled "1") is passable but I am a perfectionist. **Can anyone also help to ensure vertical centering of the multirow column?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX!SE- Try to use `tabularray` package or `ellspace` for additional vertical spaces.

Comment: I apologise that tables in latex are not my forte (in fact my worst topic in latex), but do you mind showing me an example (possibly using my above table)?

I tried to make use of the package but I have encountered too many problems with it and its documentation. (e.g. Setting fixed lengths would not work somehow , Ensuring the text would naturally wrap if it exceeds the defined cell width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec={Q[c,m, wd=15mm] Q[l,m, wd=95mm, mode=dmath] 
                          Q[r,m, wd=10mm, font=\bfseries] Q[l, m, wd=45mm]},
                 rowsep=7pt,
                 }
\SetCell[r=4]{c}    1
    &   \begin{aligned}
            f(3) & = 100  \\
            a    & =\dfrac{50}{21} - \dfrac{13}{42}b
        \end{aligned}   &   A   &   B       \\
    &   3x^2-x-4=(3x-4)(x+1)
                        &   C   &   D       \\
    &   \begin{aligned}
            f(-1) & = 0 \text{ or } f\biggl(\dfrac{4}{3}\biggr) = 0  \\
                b & = -\dfrac{2}{3}a
        \end{aligned}   &   E   &   F       \\
    &   a=3,  b=-2      &   G   &   H       \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
The simplest way to left align all equations in cells (as you request in comment below) and preserve simple table code and desired vertical spaces around cells contents, is use a `array` environment. For example:

```
\begin{array}{@{}l}
            f(3)  = 100 \\
            a     =\dfrac{50}{21} - \dfrac{13}{42}b
\end{array}
```

For shorter writing it may be handy to define new environmentČ

```
\newenvironment{la}%
    {
    \begin{array}{@{} l}
    }
    {
    \end{array}
    }
```

The MWE, which contain both ways of arrays writing is:

```
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\newenvironment{la}%
    {
    \begin{array}{@{} l}
    }
    {
    \end{array}
    }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec={Q[c,m, wd=15mm] Q[l,m, wd=95mm, mode=dmath]
                          Q[r,m, wd=10mm, font=\bfseries] Q[l, m, wd=45mm]},
                 row{1} = {font=\bfseries, mode=text},
                 row{2-Z} ={rowsep=7pt},
                 }
no. & equations         & right & left      \\
\SetCell[r=4]{c}    1
    &   \begin{array}{@{} l}
            f(3) = 100  \\
            a    = \dfrac{50}{21} - \dfrac{13}{42}b
        \end{array}     &   A   &   B       \\
    &   3x^2-x-4=(3x-4)(x+1)
                        &   C   &   D       \\
    &   \begin{la}
            f(-1) = 0 \quad\text{or}\quad f\biggl(\dfrac{4}{3}\biggr) = 0 \\
                b = -\dfrac{2}{3}a\hfill
        \end{la}        &   E   &   F       \\
    &   a=3,  b=-2      &   G   &   H       \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if I do not want to use \begin{aligned} as I want each math line to start at the left side of the cell? I've played around with your code by removing \begin{aligned} and the letters are no longer vertically centered.

Comment: See *addendum* to answer

Comment: It works now, but may I confirm if there are any updates on a more elegant solution?

Comment: it will also work with `array`. See  addendum 2.

Comment: I tried adding headings to the table, the headings were not vertically centered. I also tried to use tikzpicture and polylongdiv in the math column of the table - same problem too. Any suggestions on fixing this?

Comment: @EnergeticElectrification, yes: ask new question, where show how you try this ;-)-. Then I (or anyone) more easily help you. Column headers should be vertically centered, I'm not familiar with  `polylongdiv`, but this I don't see, why is not. SO, please new question where you show, what you try so far!

Comment: Closing this question now, will start a new thread! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why close question? It is just fine and you receive nice answers. You can ask new mušatino and left this as is.

Comment: By "close", I meant I will stop adding onto this thread. Sorry about that misunderstanding!

Comment: @EnergeticElectrification, I shortened answer, define new environment and add column titles to your table. Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Definitely helped. Thanks!

Comment: May I ask how can I prevent the 36 errors from popping up upon compiling the code?

Comment: @EnergeticElectrification, what errors? What you doing with proposed MWE? It is tested by recent MiKTeX: no warnings, no errors, no bad boxes. Using Overleaf at standalone document class you will get one warnings, since Overleaf doesn't handle `standalone` documentclass well. At it is better to use `article` document class (now commented in MWE).

Comment: My apologies, I was compiling your previous code. The new code have no errors, sorry about that! I will take in mind what you have just said though.

Answer (score 2):

The package `nicematrix` helps to solve several issues, with a simpler code.

The environment `NiceTabularX` allows to keep the table within the text area. `\begin{NiceTabularX}{<total width>}{ X ....`

`\Block{<nro of rows - nro of columns>}{<content>}` will center the content in the allocated space (e.g a 3x1 cell in this example) and allows to use `\\` inside.

`hvlines` will draw all lines.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.5in, showframe]{geometry}% added showframe <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{nicematrix} % added <<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
\large

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} % centered column
\newcolumntype{B}[1]{>{\bfseries\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} % bold column

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\noindent\begin{NiceTabularX}{\linewidth}{X C{9.5cm} B{1cm} C{4.5cm} }[hvlines] 
\Block{8-1}{1}  &\Block{3-1}{$\begin{aligned}
                                f(3)    & = 100 \\ 
                                    a   &=\dfrac{50}{21}-\dfrac{13}{42}b
                            \end{aligned}$ }                                                        &\Block{3-1}{A} &\Block{3-1}{B} \\                      
                &                                                                                   &               &       \\              
                &                                                                                   &               &       \\                  
                & $3x^2-x-4=(3x-4)(x+1)$                                                            &C              & D     \\
                &\Block{3-1}{$\begin{aligned}
                        f(-1)   & = 0 \text{ or } f\biggl(\dfrac{4}{3}\biggr) = 0\\
                            b   & = -\dfrac{2}{3}a
                \end{aligned}$}                                                                     &\Block{3-1}{E} & \Block{3-1}{F} \\                 
                &                                                                                   &               &       \\
                &                                                                                   &               &       \\                                          
                & $a=3, \; b=-2$                                                                    &G              & H     \\
\end{NiceTabularX}
        
\end{document}
```

Comment: What if I do not want to use \begin{aligned} as I want each math line to start at the left side of the cell?

Comment: See addendum to answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do this using `nicematrix`. You must compile twice.

- `\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 2pt}` will increase spacing to accommodate your big fractions.
- column types `wc`, `wl` and `wr` allow you to set the column width.
- Option `[hvlines]` for horizontal and vertical lines (but respect the blocks).
- To center the `1` in the first column, use `\Block{4-1}{1}` in cell 1-1. `{4-1}` indicates a block of 4 rows and 1 column.
- `\Block[l]{}{line1\\line2}` permits multiline cells. This is known as a "mono-cell" block. To increase vertical spacing, I used `\\[1ex]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\large
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{center}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 2pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{wc{1.5cm}wl{9.5cm}wr{1cm}wl{4.5cm}}[hvlines]
\Block{4-1}{1} & \Block[l]{}{$f(3)=100$\\[1ex]$a=\dfrac{50}{21}-\dfrac{13}{42}b$} & \textbf{A} & B \\
 & $3x^2-x-4=(3x-4)(x+1)$ & \textbf{C} & D \\
 & \Block[l]{}{$f(-1) = 0$ or $f(\dfrac{4}{3}) = 0$\\[1ex]$b=-\dfrac{2}{3}a$} & \textbf{E} & F \\
 & $a=3, \; b=-2$ & \textbf{G} & H
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```